# The merge tool is not showing when call Workspace.ResolveConflict method in TFS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am calling ResolveConflict method on my TFS WorkSpace:
`this.workspace.ResolveConflict(conflict, out resolvedConflicts)`

 In TFS 2010, it will show the merge tool `diffmerge.exe`.But it doesn't show any merge tool in TFS 2012. According to this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx, I know the `diffmerge.exe` has been removed in VS 2012, The new tool is `vsDiffmerge.exe`. I can find the tool in my VS 2012 installation directory. But it doesn't show the tool when call the ResolveConflict method. Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve it?

Comment: Hmm... the article you linked to also talks about TFS 2012 reporting (potentially) less conflicts than TFS 2010 did. Could that be the issue? I.e. that the conflict is "automatically" resolved for you with 2012.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the article is wrong. Ignore it. But I am sure that the conflict is not resolved automatically in VS2012. I don't know why this is.